# получить значения скролла во время прокрутки на js

Tags: javascript

как мне получить значения при прокрутки документa на чистом js?
 структура документа такая,fullpage слайдер

```html
<main class="wrap container">
      <div class="layout"> 
        <section id="section1">
        </section>
        <section id="section2">
        </section>
        <section id="section3">
        </section>
     </div>
</main>
```

пробовал методом 
                 `window.pageY
                 window.pageYOffset
                 window.scrollTop
                 window.clientY`
ничего не смог не получит ни найти

Comment: `document.querySelector(".wrap.container").scrollTop` ?

Comment: нет не получается,когда скроллишь получается значения 0

Comment: Так, а что именно скроллится? Если страница, можно попробовать `document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop` >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618545/body-scrolltop-vs-documentelement-scrolltop-vs-window-pageyoffset-vs-window-scro

Comment: скроллится само контент main.wrap,в определенной точки скролла нужно добавить несколько функции . щас попробую

Comment: ничего    получается  ((

Answer (score 1):

`e.target.scrollTop` и `e.target.scrollLeft`

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь этим:

```
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    });
```

Этот код добавляет слушатель события прокручивания `scroll` на окно браузера `window`. При срабатывании события вызывается функция-обработчик (`элемент.addEventListener(событие, cb-функция)`). А уже в этой функции проводим манипуляции с `элемент.pageYOffset`, который выведет нам положение страницы по Y в пикселях. Например выводим координату в консоль с помощью `console.log(данные_для_вывода)`.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Такой ответ более подходящий?)
@aleksandrbarakin